# How to skip the NaN value when doing manipulation of data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, data-manipulation

I have a data frame

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({
'BRAND': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
'STATUT':['Trading', 'Trading', 'Trading', 'Trading'],
'ID_1': [str(144), str(205), str(123), np.NaN],
'ID_2': [str(173), np.NaN, '0123', str(124)],
'ID_3': ['0897', np.NaN, np.NaN,np.NaN],
})
```

[image]

and I want to have a new column have the IDs joined together in a new column with just the numbers and skip the NaN values. And each value is wrapped by a single quotation mark and separated by a coma. Like the picture showed below:
[image]

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
dfx['new'] = dfx[['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3']].apply(lambda x: "'" + "','".join(x.dropna()) + "'", axis=1)
```

---

```
  BRAND   STATUT ID_1  ID_2  ID_3                 new
0     A  Trading  144   173  0897  '144','173','0897'
1     B  Trading  205   NaN   NaN               '205'
2     C  Trading  123  0123   NaN        '123','0123'
3     D  Trading  NaN   124   NaN               '124'
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you!! :)

Comment: No worries, make sure to upvote and mark as accepted :)